# Get Azure storage blob url after uploading powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

How can i get url of the blob i just uploaded using powershell.My code currently is

```
$storagekey=Get-AzureStorageKey -StorageAccountName appstorageacc
$ctx=New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName 
appstorageacc -   StorageAccountKey $storagekey.Primary
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File C:\Package\StarterSite.zip 
-Container   clouddata -Context $ctx -Force
```

Blob is uploaded successfully, but how can i get it's url out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Retrieve blob information using the [Get-AzureStorageBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn806392.aspx) cmdlet and select the `AbsoluteUri`:

```
(Get-AzureStorageBlob -blob 'StarterSite.zip' -Container 'clouddata ').ICloudBlob.uri.AbsoluteUri
```

Comment: How did you find this? Looking at the object/properties returned from Get-AzureStorageBlob, I had no indication there was more info available.

Comment: @Orangutech At the bottom in the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/get-azurestorageblob?view=azurermps-6.13.0) you see the output of the cmdlet

Answer (score 4):

#### Another option: just capture the result of `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent`

```bsh
$result = Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File C:\Package\StarterSite.zip
$blobUri = $result.ICloudBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri
```

It's not necessary to call `Get-AzureStorageBlob` after calling `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent`.

`Set-AzureStorageBlobContent` returns the same object type that `Get-AzureStorageBlob` returns.

#### More details

The output type is `AzureStorageBlob` for both [`Get-AzureStorageBlob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/get-azurestorageblob?view=azurermps-6.13.0#outputs) and [`Set-AzureStorageBlobContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/set-azurestorageblobcontent?view=azurermps-6.13.0#outputs)

[`AzureStorageBlob` has a ICloudBlob property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.commands.common.storage.resourcemodel.azurestorageblob?view=azurerm-ps)

[`AzureStorageBlob.ICloudBlob` getter returns a `CloudBlob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.commands.common.storage.resourcemodel.azurestorageblob.icloudblob?view=azurerm-ps#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Commands_Common_Storage_ResourceModel_AzureStorageBlob_ICloudBlob) which has the `Uri` property